# email not sending after successful registered : Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**email not sending after successful registered.** 
email not sending to the `user email` but data is coming properly to the database after successful registered.

it would be great if anybody could figure out where i am doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

serializers.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Username', max_length=30)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    token = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'email',
            'password',
            'token',
        ]


    def create(self, data):
        username = data['username']
        email = data['email']
        user_queryset = User.objects.filter(Q(email__iexact=email) | Q(username__iexact=username)).first()
        password = data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**data)

        subject = "test subject"
        message = "test message"
        from_email = settings.FROM_EMAIL
        to_mail = email

        if user_queryset == None:
            if password is not None:
                instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()

            if subject and message and from_email:
                try:
                    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_mail, fail_silently=False)
                except BadHeaderError:
                   return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')

            return instance



        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User Already Exists!")
```

views.py

```
class RegisterAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        register_serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=data)
        if register_serializer.is_valid():
            register_serializer.save()
            new_register = register_serializer.data
            return Response(new_register, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({"msg":"invalid credential"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
            return instance
```

Above of:

```
  if subject and message and from_email:
      try:
          send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_mail)
      except BadHeaderError:
          return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
      return HttpResponse('thank you for register!')
```

you need to move the `return instance` down and you probably don't want to return a `HttpResponse`

**EDIT:**

Current code in answer:

```
  return instance
  if subject and message and from_email:
      try:
          send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_mail)
      except BadHeaderError:
          return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
      return HttpResponse('thank you for register!')
```

Suggested Change:

```
   if subject and message and from_email:
       try:
           send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_mail)
       except BadHeaderError:
           # do something
   return instance
```

Comment: you mean, i have to remove  `HttpResponse` and change the position of `return instance` down after `HttpResponse` @bb4L